Decision Tree prediction for the fail reason
In my experiment, I used Decision Trees to predict whether participants will pass or fail, and I will provide feedback to them based on the reason for their failure. The Decision Tree includes three attributes. My question is: If a participant is predicted to fail, how can I determine the reason for their failure? Is the node just before the failure the reason for the failure? What is the best criterion to choose among the three attributes associated with failing?
Thanks for your attention.
